# I am getting exception at this line of code

Tags: android, flutter, exception, gradle, annotations

implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'

The exception is
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\ayush\AndroidStudioProjects\fyp\android\build.gradle' line: 25
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I had try to change the version to newer but still I am getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

you added implementation in the root `build.gradle`. you must add it in the app `build.gradle`

[image]

first `build.gradle` is global and second is app `build.gradle`. dependency must be added here.